# How do I log in to a site in Selenium4 with Python - if the browser itself asks for Sign in BEFORE letting me open the site

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser

I am at my wits end.

I know how to log in with Selenium. But I do not succeed in logging in to a publish-dev-Site to test. The browser itself asks me to login before even redirecting me to the site. Because of this I cannot read an XPath, CSS, NAME/ there is no XPATH, CSS, NAME.
What am I missing/ do not know?

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("xyz")

sign_in_username_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Username")
sign_in_password_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Password")

sign_in_username_input.send_keys("ABC")
sign_in_password_input.send_keys("DEF")

sign_in_login_button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Sign in")
sign_in_login_button.click()
```

And here's a pic:

[image: publish-dev site with browser-popup]

Comment: That's asking for Basic Authentication (BasicAuth) credentials and those are sent in HTTP headers encoded in base64.

Comment: Can you tell me how to log in? Im quite the noob...

Answer (score 1):

Try passing credentials in the URL, see if that works.

**Syntax:** `https://<username>:<password>@<domain>`

Check the code below:

```
url = "http://username:password@site.com"
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately not. I get:
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})

  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument

Comment: Wait! I made a mistake!

Comment: Yes! It works. Thank you very much!